# FQL request on facebook developers tool not work anymore for me

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Right now I'm a bit confused what happen because a few days ago it still work but now I get  this issue:

When I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and on the tab fql query I put the query below:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=MYUID  AND page_id=MYPAGEID
```

When I submit , i receive no result:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

So I'm confused about where is the mistake, is it about the syntax I write my query or Facebook developers haved move on some changes in the FQL Language.

Someone help, please.Thank you

Comment: Are you using API version 1.0 or 2.0? - does the access token you're using have user_likes permission?

Comment: I use the API version 2.0, and you have reason, I forgot to grant the permission "user_likes" in my scope but I don't know why earlier, few days before it still work even if I miss this permission. But anyways, it does the trick.My problem is solved,thanks a loat Igy